# click a button to pop up input box to set up range to update then run multiple macros within the range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to find a solution that reduces my manual work.
So, I have multiple macros that updates Week 1 to Week N.
For example, macro 1 updates values on row 2 from wk x to wk y.
and macro 2 updates values on row 3 from wk x to wk y.
and macro 3 updates values on row 4 from wk x to wk y.

Also, I made a button to run those 3 macros at once with following code.

```
Sub one_click()

Call macro1
Call macro2
Call macro3

End Sub
```

But, problem is....Every time I want to update values from wk x to wk y, I need to set up the range (x,y) for 3 macros. (x,y are same for 3 macros) 

Thus, my desired process is: 
1. Click a button 
2. Pop up input box 1 with a msg: Please enter your starting column# 
3. Pop up input box 2 with a msg: Please enter your ending column# 
4. Run macro 1,2,3 at once within given range. 
5. If error happens, show msgbox: You are not connected to SQL server. 

Does VBA have a function or code that makes it possible?

 Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.InputBox` to receive a user input. A few things you will want to code for

1. The input should be numeric (Test = `IsNumeric`)
2. The inputs cannot be 0 or negative (No columns exist with such index #s)
3. The ending column should be larger than the starting column (Else, the logic in the nested procedures is likely to be reversed or error out)

---

Once you have validated the input, you can then pass these along to other Sub Procedures by simply stating the name of sub followed by the variable you want to pass along.
**Syntax:** `Sub_Procedure Variable`

If you test the below code, and provide valid entries, you will receive a `MsgBox` with those entries from other subs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example_Master()

Dim sCol As Integer 'Start Column
Dim eCol As Integer 'End Column

On Error Resume Next
    sCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Starting Column", "Column", Type:=2)
    eCol = Application.InputBox("Enter Ending Column", "Column", Type:=2)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not IsNumeric(sCol) Or sCol < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Starting Entry"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(eCol) Or eCol < sCol Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Ending Entry"
    Exit Sub
End If

Example1 sCol
Example2 eCol

End Sub
```

```
Sub Example1(sCol As Integer)
    MsgBox sCol
End Sub
```

```
Sub Example2(eCol As Integer)
    MsgBox eCol
End Sub
```

*Side Note:* You are going to want to look up error handling with nested procedures like this

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer!!
so,
macro1 sCol
macro2 eCol

End Sub

Sub macro1(sCol, eCol As Integer)
     Do While (sCol < eCol + 1)
     rows(xxxxx)
     Loop
End Sub

does it make sense?